# css in portrait mode and land mode with @media

Tags: css, media-queries

I have the css below. What I want is kind of fluid / liquid (for lack of right terminology) css. I am developing for mobile and when I change the modes
 from portrait view to land view, I want it to flow nicely. Right now the image in

```
<div class="parentDivision-separator-middle" style="margin-top: 3px;"><div class="image childDivision7"></div>
```

works great for the land view but in portrait view it leaves a lot of space after the separator image. If I take out the !important from css then it starts to cut off the image. Had been fooling around with it since yesterday. Any help will be appreciated

```
<style>

    div.parentDivision {
        margin-top:2px;
    }
    div.parentDivision div {
        height:281px;
        background-size: 100%;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
    }

    @media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
        div.parentDivision div {
            height:151px;
            background-size: 100%;
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
        }
        div.parentDivision-separator-middle {
            height:151px ;
            background-size: 100%;
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
        }
    }
    @media screen and (max-width: 320px) {
        div.parentDivision div {
            height:151px !important;
            background-size: 100%;
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
        }
        div.parentDivision-separator-middle {
            height:151px  !important;
            background-size: 100%;
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
        }

    }
    div.parentDivision-separator-middle {
        height:165px  !important;
        background-size: 100%;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
    }
    div.parentDivision .childDivision1 {
        background-image:url(http://www.bryantsmith.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2011/10/cssediter1.png);
    }
    div.parentDivision .childDivision2 {
        background-image:url(http://www.bryantsmith.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2011/10/cssediter1.png);
    }
    div.parentDivision .childDivision3 {
        background-image:url(http://www.bryantsmith.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2011/10/cssediter1.png);
    }
    div.parentDivision .childDivision4 {
        background-image:url(http://www.bryantsmith.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2011/10/cssediter1.png);
    }
    div.parentDivision .childDivision5 {
        background-image:url(http://www.bryantsmith.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2011/10/cssediter1.png);
    }
    div.parentDivision .childDivision6 {
        background-image:url(http://www.bryantsmith.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2011/10/cssediter1.png);
    }
    div.parentDivision .childDivision7 {
        background-image:url(http://www.bryantsmith.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2011/10/cssediter1.png);
    }
    div.image {
        margin: 1px;
    }
    div.parentDivision-separator-left {
        float: left;
        width: 49%;
        overflow: hidden;
    }
    div.parentDivision-separator-right {
        float: left;
        width: 49%;
        overflow: hidden;
        margin-left: 2%;
    }

    div.parentDivision-separator-middle {
        float: left;
        width: 100%;
        overflow: hidden;
    }
    div.parentDivision-separator div.image {
        padding: 2px;
    }



</style>


<div class="list-wrapper parentDivision">
    <div class="parentDivision-separator-left"><div class="image childDivision1"></div></div>
    <div class="parentDivision-separator-right"><div class="image childDivision2"></div></div>
</div>
<div class="list-wrapper parentDivision">
    <div class="parentDivision-separator-middle" style="margin-top: 3px;"><div class="image childDivision7"></div></div>
</div>
<div class="list-wrapper parentDivision">
    <div class="parentDivision-separator-left"><div class="image childDivision3"></div></div>
    <div class="parentDivision-separator-right"><div class="image childDivision4"></div></div></div>
</div>
<div class="list-wrapper parentDivision">
    <div class="parentDivision-separator-middle" style="margin-top: 3px;"><div class="image childDivision7"></div></div>
</div>
<div class="list-wrapper parentDivision">
    <div class="parentDivision-separator-left"><div class="image childDivision5"></div></div>
    <div class="parentDivision-separator-right"><div class="image childDivision6"></div></div>
</div>
```

Here is jsfiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/yYSke/

If you make the browser bigger or smaller you will see the images get cut off

Comment: Couple of things... your questions seems to have been chopped up - not quite sure of the end result you're after. Secondly, can you set up a fiddle?

Comment: adding js fiddle to question. If you move browser and make it bigger or smaller you will see the images will start cutting off or loose the originality http://jsfiddle.net/yYSke/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see that the images are cut off, be they portrait or landscape (with the !important height included). I also see no gaps.

Is the following what you desire? http://jsfiddle.net/yYSke/2/show/

First of all I changed the background images so they have 100% height, and an auto width to keep the aspect ratio. I then set them to be centred in the element:

```
div.parentDivision div {
    height:281px;
    background-size: auto 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
     background-position: center;
}
```

I also stripped out some of the code in your media queries as you're just repeating what you already have in the base styles.

Now you'll notice that the image in `parentDivision-separator-middle` is too large to fit inside the container without being cut off or overlapping. That is because the height set on parentDivision-separator-middle is smaller than `childDivision7` where you set the image. I avoided that by setting the height to inherit:

```
div.parentDivision .childDivision7 {
        background-image:url(http://www.bryantsmith.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2011/10/cssediter1.png);
        height: inherit;
    }
```

There are other areas where the code could be cleaned up, but I think this gives you what you're looking for?